# Magento 2.3.5 how to add canonical links for cms pages having slash at the end of url-key

Tags: cms-pages, url-key, magento2.3.5-p1, canonical, custom-layout-update

I am using magento 2.3.5p1 community edition.

I want to add canonical links in cms pages.

As in 2.3.5 magento we have to create a separate layout update file as cms_page_view_selectable_[cms-url-key]_[custom-layout-name].xml .

But the issue is I have url keys of my cms pages with trailing slash as example-key/ saved in admin for all cms pages because I wanted to generate cms page urls with slash in sitemap.

But with these urls I am unable to create the given layout update file.

Please provide a solution.

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

please follow below steps:-
**system.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_file.xsd">
    <system>
       <tab id="vendor" translate="label" sortOrder="300">
            <label>M-Connect Media</label>
        </tab>
        
        <section id="module_cpcu" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="140" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
            <label>CMS Page Canonical Url</label>
            <tab>vendor</tab> 
            
            <resource>Vendor_Module::config_cpcu</resource> 
            
            <group id="general" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="2" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                <label>General Setting</label>
                
                <field id="active" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                    <label>Enable/Disable</label>
                    <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno</source_model>
                </field>
                
                <field id="trailing_slash" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="2" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                    <label>Remove Trailing slash </label>
                    <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno</source_model>
                </field>                            
                
            </group>            
            
        </section>       
    </system>
</config>
```

**Vendor/Module/etc/fronend/events.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
   
    <event name="layout_load_before">
        <observer name="seo_layout_load_before" instance="Vendor\Module\Observer\LayoutLoadBefore" />
    </event> 
    
    
</config>
```

Now in your helper file
**Vendor/Module/Helper/Data.php**

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Helper;

class Data extends \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper 
{       
         
    public function getConfig($configPath) {
        return $this->scopeConfig->getValue(
            $configPath, \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE
        );
    }
        
        
        
}
```

Now create a observer
**Vendor/Module/Observer/LayoutLoadBefore.php**

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList;

class LayoutLoadBefore implements ObserverInterface
{   
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Page\Config $page,
        \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface $urlInterface,
        \Mconnectmedia\CmsPageCanonicalUrl\Helper\Data $helper,
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger
    )
    {

        $this->page          = $page;
        $this->urlInterface = $urlInterface;
        $this->helper = $helper;
        $this->logger        = $logger;
    }
    
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    { 
        $active=$this->helper->getConfig('module_cpcu/general/active');
        if($active){        
            $action = $observer->getEvent()->getFullActionName();       
            
            if ($action == 'cms_page_view' || $action == 'cms_index_index') {   

                $canonicalUrl= $this->urlInterface->getCurrentUrl();
                $trailing_slash=$this->helper->getConfig('module_cpcu/general/trailing_slash');
                    if($trailing_slash){
                        $canonicalUrl=rtrim($canonicalUrl,'/'); 
                    }               
                    
                $this->page->addRemotePageAsset(
                    $canonicalUrl,
                    'canonical',
                    ['attributes' => ['rel' => 'canonical']]
                );          
            }   
            
            return $this;
        }
    }   
   
}
```

**Vendor/Module/etc/adminhtml/routes.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="admin">
        <route id="module" frontName="module">
            <module name="Vendor_Module" before="Magento_Backend" />
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

Now run `setup:upgrade` and `static-content:deploy -f` and `flush cache`

**Hope this helps**